# Custom Select Attribut in admin have different values set than InstallData

Tags: magento2, eav, custom-attributes, attribute-options, installdata

I'm trying to make a 3 value select attribut in the customer edit page in admin.
The attribut is created in DB after `setup:upgrade` but stored in `eav_attribute_option` table as follow :

[image]

the value sent in post request when editing a customer is the `option_id` not the values set in the `InstallData.php`

```
'label' => 'My Label',
'type' => 'varchar',
'input' => 'select',
'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
'position' => 1001,
'visible' => true,
'required' => false,
'is_used_in_grid' => true,
'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
'system' => 0,
'user_defined' => true,
'option' => [
    'values' => [
        0 => 'Default',
        1 => 'No',
        2 => 'Yes',
    ]
]
```

Labels are shown correctly in admin but not their values.

[image]

I suspect `source`, and trying `int` instead of `varchar` produced an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://www.w3solver.com/code-to-show-different-mode-list-or-grid-mode-for-different-category/)

the above link is creating one attribute, you need to add a different source to provide your custom options value. 
check line 29

```
'source' => 'W3solver\Customcategorymode\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Showmode',
```

then create the source file and add code

```
public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('No')],
                ['value' => 2, 'label' => __('Yes')],
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
```

Comment: wasn't working at first because I deleted `'system' => 0,` line, Thank you !